# Where's the memory going?

Tags: windows-7, memory, task-manager, resource-monitor

I'm getting Out of Memory errors in one of my programs (I'm a programmer).
This is ridiculous, because I have 16GB RAM on a Windows 7 x64 system, and no reason why I should be running out.  So I investigated, and looked between Resource Monitor and Task Manager to find what's using all my memory:

[image]

Notice: 15,158 KB memory in use.  But at a glance, the amount of memory actually being used by programs does not add up.  I plugged in actual figures from Task Manager (note, "Show Processes from All Users" is checked!) and got to about 10.7 GB before getting into all the teensy little <50MB programs.  So where's the remaining 4+ GB of memory gone to?

Comment: You can use RAMMap to investigate the use of physical memory. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229 However, out of memory messages usually refer to virtual memory. A 32bit process would normally be restricted to 2GB virtual memory. I assume you have a page file.

Comment: I wonder if your program is only allocated x amount of resources. I've had the same issue creating a log file, Visaul Studio tells me out of memory and I've used 4 or 5 GB of my 16GB! It may have something to do with the program you're writing being 32bit instead of 64bit

Comment: Chrome by itself is using almost 2.5GB of your memory.  So you are actually using around 15GB.

Comment: You can copy data from Task Manager, and paste in Excel. Then you can use formula and check that memory is not elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't follow your conclusion. On the screenshot there are 25 processes that add up to about 11GB but there are about 150 processes which you didn't add as you stated because they are to small. If you take those ~150 processes and assume an average of 25MB per process you will get ~4GB which corresponds the amount of Memory you claim to be missing! I would recommend you have a closer look at the teensy little <50MB programs and recalculate.

Comment: Except that that's a faulty assumption.  There are not 150 other processes, and the average is way less than 25 MB.  Somewhere there are some undocumented processes.  I just rebooted and recalculated again with fewer processes in memory, and I still come to the inescapable conclusion that there is something other than the processes displayed consuming around 3GB of RAM

Comment: @Shaul as long as you don't give us all the information we have to assume something... sometimes it is faulty, but according to the scroll bar in the Task Manager I guessed that there are about 6-7 times more processes running...

Comment: Well, well, I just discovered that you can copy and paste rows from Resource Monitor into Excel... and it turns out that the calculation is correct, after all.  I'm so embarrassed... :-/